# I want to add searchview to my listview

Tags: java, android, listview, search

I want to add searchview to my listview in MainActivity.java please,how?

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<SearchView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/searchView1"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:queryHint="search"/>

<ListView
android:id="@+id/listview"
android:layout_below="@+id/searchView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        // 1. pass context and data to the custom adapter
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, generateData());
        //2. setListAdapter
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
    private ArrayList < Item > generateData() {
        ArrayList < Item > items = new ArrayList < Item > ();
        items.add(new Item("item1", "description1"));
        items.add(new Item("item2", "description2"));
        items.add(new Item("item3", "description3"));
        return items;
    }@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu); //Menu Resource, Menu
        return true;
    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.about:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, about.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the XML Layout with **ListView** and **SearchView** as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Create The Following Java Class As **SearchViewFilterMode.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;

/**
 * Shows a list that can be filtered in-place with a SearchView in non-iconified mode.
 */
public class SearchViewFilterMode extends Activity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private ListView mListView;

    private final String[] mStrings = Cheeses.sCheeseStrings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

        setContentView(R.layout.searchview_filter);

        mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mStrings));
        mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        setupSearchView();
    }

    private void setupSearchView() {
        mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true); 
        mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search Here");
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
            mListView.clearTextFilter();
        } else {
            mListView.setFilterText(newText.toString());
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What about MainActivity.java?

Comment: @abood250 use this SearchViewFilterMode as main activity

Comment: No please, I want to add it to my MainActivity.java above !!

Comment: What if I add EditText filter in activity_main.xml with id=searchbox how it's going to be in ActivityMain.java?

Comment: @abood250 change the name thats it? try to make some changes in the code rather looking for everything readymade